# create a slider without using a plugin in jquery

Tags: jquery, slider

I can't do this slider (at jquery)
How the slider works:
It should work when the arrow next to it is pressed
2.It should work if the pagination at the bottom is pressed (with the slide id at the top)
3. The slider should work automatically

The slider view is on this site:

Comment: You need more focus, we can't work for you. Try and then when you are stuck post here your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="image1.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="image2.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="image3.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="image4.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="image6.jpg" /></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load (function() {
    var theImage = $('ul li img');
    var theWidth = theImage.width()
    //wrap into mother div
    $('ul').wrap('<div id="mother" />');
    //assign height width and overflow hidden to mother
    $('#mother').css({
        width: function() {
        return theWidth;
      },
        height: function() {
        return theImage.height();
      },
        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'hidden'
    });
        //get total of image sizes and set as width for ul
    var totalWidth = theImage.length * theWidth;
    $('ul').css({
        width: function(){
        return totalWidth;
    }
    });

});//doc ready

</script>
```